# How to implemement smooth side scrolling in a DOS game?

Tags: platformer, side-scroller, scrolling

I'm about to develop (just for fun) a retro DOS game with Turbo C 2.01. Currently I'm wirting directly all the pixel information to `0xA0000000 + [y * 320 + x]` which is very slow. My vision is to build a game which scrolls very smoothly over the tile map - just like this one (to name one example): http://www.doshaven.eu/game/dark-quest/.

I researched a bit online and found out that there is a *attribute controller register* where you can write to 13h a 4-bit pixel offset value.

```
inp(0x3da);             
outp(0x3c0, 0x13 | 0x20);
outp(0x3c0, offset_in_x);
```

But it scrolls my screen only about 16 pixels and I read that this number is limited by the graphics mode (which I confirmed in some tests).

**So how is this properly done?**

Comment: Could you add an animated gif of the effect you'd like to have?

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for [Adaptive Tile Refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_tile_refresh) - I don't know the implementation details myself, but maybe someone else can jump in? :)

Comment: Very few people are going to go through the trouble of installing a random game just to answer your question.

Comment: Also, are you writing the pixels with individual calls?

Answer (score 1):

I may have to see if I can use the port call. As of now, I do it via software which is a lot of loop de doo.  First I pre string 4 320x200 images together while  slicing them into 10x200 segments, creating a 1280x200 buffer array.  I can scroll the 10x200 slices, back and fourth. It works fine for the most part but struggles a little on slow machines. I am struggling to write it in assembly, as it is a bit complicated. In the mean time I am looking at other alternatives myself.

```
void makesigbuff(char *dest,int width,int height,int dir,int map ) {
register unsigned  long count=0,l=0,k=0;
register unsigned  long i=0,j=0,frames=0;

register long endsig=10;
register long startsig=0;
register long imgs=0;
register long startplace = dir;
 do {


    count = 0;

    k=0;

    for(j=0;j < height + startplace;j++) {

       for(i=0;i < endsig;i++) {

         if(i >= startsig) {  // i > ... to see it in sigments.

             if(j >= startplace) {

                  dest[count+i]=splicearray[frames + map][k];    //+map

             }
             k++;
        }

     }

     if(j>=startplace) {
          count += 320;    bitwidth;  //SCREEN_WIDTH;
     }
   }

   startsig +=10;
   endsig+=10;
   frames++;

 }while(frames < 32 ); //128


}
```